# Can we rename the MUSR_MQADMIN with some other user

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using IBM MQ version 9.0 windows server. We require a little information about MUSR_MQADMIN. Can we rename MUSR_MQADMIN to some other user? If it's renamed to some other user and pointing to the "IBM Websphere MQ services", will it face any challenges?

@Team,

we have a one more question why we always get the " error 1069:the services didn't start due to the logon error " and we have seen logon properties ./musr_mqadmin is having some encrypted password.Kindly confirm us after installation this password is created by with operational user password( mqm@123 )( means Ex: user : op_mqm & password : mqm@123 )or is there any default password ? if it is default password how we can decrypt the default password

Comment: I don't believe you can. However, not 100% certain so waiting to see if any other experts jump in to say you can.

Comment: @praveen are all users that will access the queue manager local users on the server or do any domain users access the queue manager?  If domain users access it them you will have problems when not running it as a domain user.  I have not tried but I think you can fill in any user as long as you have the right password in the setup wizard, this is normally a domain user, but I would not see why a local user would not be rejected, I think the KC tells you all the permissions the user needs, such as being a member of the mqm group.

Comment: `MUSR_MQADMIN` is only used if you do not provide MQ a user to use in the install wizard.  As far as renaming the existing account it may work since it should be part of the mqm group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, default user MUSR_MQADMIN can be deleted, before that you should create another user account and make this user member of mqm group, then associate this new user name with IBM MQ Services. If you are working with MQ Client then MUSR_MQADMIN user is NOT needed.
I have tried this and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for support.